# Subpixel bleed with external monitor 4k 60hz in ubuntu 22.04 and 23.10

Tags: 22.04, 23.10, antialiasing, subpixel-rendering

Getting subpixel bleep with my new laptop connected to an external 4k monitor over hdmi at 60hz. It goes away if i set it to 30hz but it is horrible at 30hz.

Happens both in ubuntu 22.04 and 23.10.

My laptop is a MSI Modern 15 A5m for reference.

[image]